# A jquery script to find xpath location of clicked element

Tags: jquery, html, xpath, jquery-selectors

Is there any way to change jquery code below to find xpath location of the html code. Or is there unique jquery code regardless of the html (html is changing) Please visit: http://jsbin.com/uhude3/19/edit becouse i'm writting code there. What I need is - where i'm clicking on element to show me xpath location of div,span,p,@href... ... etc.

```
jQuery(function($) {

  $(".rightArrow").click(function() {
      var rightArrowParents = [];
      $(this).parents().not('html').each(function() {
          var entry = this.tagName.toLowerCase();
          if (this.className) {
              entry += "." + this.className.replace(/ /g, '.');
          }
          rightArrowParents.push(entry);
      });
      rightArrowParents.reverse();
      alert(rightArrowParents.join(" "));
  });

});
```

and how to change this my code UP with rhis below:

```
function getXPath( element )
{
    var xpath = '';
    for ( ; element && element.nodeType == 1; element = element.parentNode )
    {
        var id = $(element.parentNode).children(element.tagName).index(element) + 1;
        id > 1 ? (id = '[' + id + ']') : (id = '');
        xpath = '/' + element.tagName.toLowerCase() + id + xpath;
    }
    return xpath;
}
```

to when I click I get a xpath. How to combine this two codes??? http://jsbin.com/uhude3/19/edit

Comment: In case an XSLT solution is acceptable, there is a short and easy one. Do you wish to see it?

Comment: I provided a link to an XSLT solution in my answer.

Comment: I updated code my code with answer but needs to combined this two codes to work. THANKS